# Why automatic variable in my makefile doesn't find any target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've written this hello world in `hello.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  exit( 0 );
}
```

my `Makefile` is:

```
%: %.c
```

When I run `make` I will get this error: `make: *** No targets.  Stop.`

Comment: Your program won't compile, as `exit()` is defined in `stdlib.h` which you're not even including. Second, if this is all you really need to compile, just type `make hello`. Gnu make will automagically build this for you  with the default libs, headers, and compilation (though it may get confused if you have a `hello.c`, `hello.cpp`, and `hello.java` all in the same folder.)

Comment: Yes I know how to make a simple program by running `make targetname` But in this question I've simplified my origin problem. I want to know why writing `%: %.c` rule doesn't work here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your makefile provides a *rule* `%: %.c` specifying that it's extensionless executables and *.c* files that you're interested in (in fact, just the built-in rules do that much), but gives no hint that there's a source file named `hello.c` or a *target* named `hello`.

When you type `make` by itself, make takes the first target listed in the makefile as the target to be made, but your makefile contains no targets whatsoever, hence *No targets. Stop*.  In short, make has no clue that there is anything nearby with a name like `hello*`.

With your makefile as is, typing `make hello` will do what you want, as it tells make what it is that you'd like to build.

If you tell make about `hello`, you'll also be able to type just `make` to do what you want:

```
hello: hello.c

%: %.c
```

or more idiomatically and flexibly, you would list all your "top-level" targets in an `all` target:

```
all: hello

%: %.c

.PHONY: all
```

Comment: This is the best answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Typical c hello world prgram:

hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  return  0;
}
```

Typical Makefile, short but complete:

Makefile:

```
all: hello

hello: hello.o
    gcc -o "$@" hello.o
hello.o: hello.c 
    g++ -c hello.c

.PHONY:clean

clean:
    rm *.o hello
```

Example with pattern rules:

```
all: hello

hello: hello.o
    gcc -o "$@" hello.o
%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $<

.PHONY:clean

clean:
    rm *.o hello
```

Example with delimiter(`\n` as enter, `\t` as tab):

```
all: hello\n

hello: hello.o\n
\tgcc -o "$@" hello.o
%.o: %.c\n
\tgcc -c $<

.PHONY:clean

clean:\n
\trm *.o hello
```

Comment: hi @lulyon, thank. Cloud you please help me to write this make file by automatic variable and pattern rules?

Comment: @Khajavi  OK. (%.o: %.c\n\t gcc -c $<) This can be used to generate object file.

Comment: @Khajavi Take care of delimiter. It is OK on mine.